# How to detect when a batch file in a different process is prompting for input?

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I've got a series of batch files that I want to run with automated input.

They all have at least one point in their execution where they pause and ask for input. Either through:

```
set /p FOO=Please enter value for FOO:
```

or just a simple

```
pause
```

My problem is that if I redirect input and output streams the prompts only arrive in the output stream AFTER I've already sent the input. So I've got to listen to the output before the prompt to trigger my canned response.

That gets rid of two scripts. The other one however does not have any output before the first prompt.

I've tried to use Process.WaitForInputIdle but that throws an Exception saying there is no message loop on the process.

My code so far:

```
    private void Foo()
        var p = StartElevatedProcess("script.bat", true /*redirect*/);
        p.OutputDataReceived += p_OutputDataReceived;
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();
    }

    void p_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null) return;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

        if (e.Data.StartsWith("Install complete"))
        {
            ((Process)sender).StandardInput.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add a pre-prompt output to the third script.

Comment: @Kevin: I could do that but the whole point of the exercise is to not have to manually handle these files.

Comment: Just a random idea.  Do you control the batch script?  If so, an easy way to communicate between the C# thread and the cmd interpreter might be to pass data on the clipboard.  Have the batch script `(echo prompt1) | clip` then have C# do `while (!System.Windows.Forms.ContainsText("prompt1")) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50) }` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The asynchronous mode might not support this but the synchronous read on StandardOutput does!

```
        Process p = StartElevatedProcess(
            "script.bat",
            true);
        do
        {
            char[] buff = new char[1000];
            int i = p.StandardOutput.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            string output = new String(buff, 0, i);
            if (output.Contains("Please enter value for FOO:"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Foo value");
            }
            else if (output.Contains("Please enter value for BAR:"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output);
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine("Bar value");
            }
            else if (output.Contains(". . ."))
            {
                // Handle "Hit any key to continue"
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (!p.HasExited);
```

This might not be ideal. There may be issues with lines getting torn apart of a script produces a lot of output or runs very long. But hopefully this will save someone else the time to figure this out.